# How to make a t-test without a dataset?

Tags: r

With a given `n1=100`, `n2=80`, `μ1=1`, `μ2=2`, `σsquared=3`. How can one simulate data for the groups, and use the `lm()` to estimate μ1, μ2.
Are the means inequal ( R  `t.test` )?

Comment: try with [rnorm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/compositions/versions/2.0-1/topics/rnorm)

Comment: How do you think to do that?

Comment: well, the function is designed to simulate data, which seems to be what you are asking. it accepts your desired mean, your desired s, and the number of values to generate, quite straight forward

Comment: Do you know the code for lm?

Answer (score 1):

If you do a t-test by hand (formula from [here](https://www.scribbr.com/statistics/t-test/)), you could get something like this

```
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
n1 <- 100
n2 <- 80
vr <- 3

t.value <- (x1 - x2) / sqrt((vr * (1 / n1 + 1 / n2)))

dt(x = t.value, df = n1 + n2 - 2)

0.0003110459
```

`t.value` corresponds to the t value reported by `t.test` and the final result is the p-value.

Comment: This is of course the best answer, given that we assume that the OP used the word "simulate" only by accident.

Comment: ... and if we don't consider that the original poster asked about `lm`.

Comment: Misreading questions is sort of my forte.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @Sirius you can try with `rnorm`

```
n <- 100
m <- 80
mu1 <- 1
mu2 <- 2
sd <- sqrt(3)

d1 <- rnorm(n,mu1,sd)
d2 <- rnorm(m,mu2,sd)
t.test(d1,d2)
```

However, the `lm` function takes two vectors of the same length, so you can't fit a linear regression model between these data unless you extract an 80-long data sample from the `d2` distribution.

Comment: you can still use lm to estimate means, form a 100+80 long column vector and add a category variable saying which set they're in

Comment: So it won't be possible to use the lm? And when you say "OP", I don't understand exactly what you mean. Should I use 3^0.5?

Comment: Anyway: Thank you so much - both Elia and Sirus :) You are good guys.

Comment: it will be possible after all with lm, is what I am saying. @elia pointed out an obvious hurdle, but there is an ok route around it. OP = original poster, saves us from typing "he or she" or your full nick all the time. And yes, usd sd=sqrt(3)

Comment: I edited my answer to account for the sqaure root of sd. @IngAA you should follow the suggestion of @Sirius regarding the means estimation via `lm`

Comment: Okey, thanks! I just need some time to figure out how to use lm. Im quite new at this, but I want to learn. Let me know if you find a good code :)

Answer (score 0):

For two samples, a t-test of the slope of a simple linear model is essentially the same as the two sample t-test. Note however to compare this with the classical t-test (`var.equal = TRUE`) and not the Welch test.

Extending the approach of @Elia, we get:

```r
n <- 100
m <- 80
mu1 <- 1
mu2 <- 2
sd <- sqrt(3)

d1 <- rnorm(n,mu1,sd)
d2 <- rnorm(m,mu2,sd)
t.test(d1,d2)

f <- rep(c("d1", "d2"), c(n, m))
y <- c(d1, d2)

m <- lm(y ~ f)
summary(m)

## this is the same as the t-test with equal variances
t.test(y ~ f, var.equal = TRUE)

# or
t.test(d1, d2, var.equal = TRUE)
```

**Visualization:**

```r
plot(as.numeric(factor(f)), y, axes=FALSE, xlab="Sample", xlim=c(0.5, 2.5))
abline(m, col="red")
axis(1, at=c(1,2), labels=c("d1", "d2")); axis(2, las=1); box()
```

[image: linear model with 2 samples]

Discussion about t- and Welch tests, linear models etc. may be found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/